# Can't see text in Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I used Entry fields in main windows of my app and StringVar to fill it, it works. Now, I made new window and I have new Entry field which I want to fill same as Entry at first window. I tried to use same variable as Entry fields used at main window but still I can't see text.

```
def napraviGUI(self):

self.__imeTxt = StringVar()
        self.__ime_entry = Entry(panelZaPrikaz,width=35,textvariable = self.__imeTxt,state=DISABLED)
        self.__ime_entry.grid(row=2,column=2)

def popuniEntry(self,jedanPacijent):
        self.__imeTxt.set(jedanPacijent.ime)

#this is inside second window
self.__ime_pregled_entry=Entry(self.prikazPacijenta,textvariable=self.__imeTxt,width=35,state=DISABLED)

self.__ime_pregled_entry.grid(row = 1,column = 2,sticky = NW)

#and this Entry don't show text
```

Comment: You didn't show it, but this is a common symptom of using `Tk()` to make a new window, when you should be using `Toplevel()` to make additional windows.

Comment: Thanks. This was a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter is a one thread application, so you can't open two windows at the same time. The solution is to create the second window like Toplevel of the first.

You must use the command `TopLevel(first_window)`